# How do I use React Navigation with React Native 0.60.0?

Tags: react-native

As of React Native 0.60.0, I can no longer compile apps after installing the react-navigation and react-native-gesture-handler packages. It causes a compiler error:

**Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'**

Does anyone have advice on how to use React Navigation without these packages? Or is there another way to configure them?

Comment: Even I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you already try using npx?

```
    1) npm install --save-dev jetifier
    2) npx jetify
    3) npx react-native run-android
    4) npx jetify
```

Let me know if this worked

Comment: jetifier is for projects which are upgrading from 0.59 to 0.60

and already has react-navigation setup in 0.59 earlier version

Comment: @spacedev "as of react-native 0.60 I can no longer compile apps after installing...." Gesture handler is not yet updated to 0.60, you need to either change your node modules or use the jetifier to make it compile successfully and run

Comment: @Auticcat Thanks for this. I actually switched back to Java for native Android Development and I'm having a much easier time. I can't say whether or not your answer works, but I thank you for taking the time to respond.